# Simple solidity misunderstanding - how/where does it utilise blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have a rather 'new' understanding of blockchain, I have a relatively good grip on how it persists data.

I also have an understanding of the solidity syntax - fairly easy to pick up for someone already familiar with OOP principles.

What I'm failing to understand is how solidity leverages ethereum's blockchain technology.

### Question/s

Solidity looks like an object-oriented programming language to me, at what point does it persist data to the blockchain?

What denotes a 'block' given the fact the examples simply look like classes - is each instance of these classes a 'block'?

### Context:

The solidity example I'm going off: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.6/solidity-by-example.html

Answer (score 0):

A block in a blockchain is the ledger of Information About the Transactions. So whenver we store the data it is writeen as a Transaction in a block.

When you write a solidity Code after compilation the abi file and bytecode is created. In the blockchain we store the Bytecode file not the solidity Code. Whereas the ABI file is use to interact with the Smart Contract with the help of Web3 Library. The solidity Code can be added as a good programming practise but not necessary.

After deploying the smartcontract you get the address to Access the smart contract to interact with.

Now whenever you update the values of a variable in solidity it will consider as a Transaction and that Transaction will be store in the next block.

I hope its clear to you now.

Thanks smarx and jfc for correcting :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, that's helpful. My question is, specifically, with regard to `whenever you update the values of a variable in solidity it will consider`. So is each block a 'version' of all of the properties which belong to a contract? i.e. as soon as one of the (many possible) properties in a contract changes - it's saved to the blockchain?

Comment: The block is not dedicated with the Transaction of a particular smartcontract. A block has the Transactions like sending ethereum and different Transactions from different smart contracts. Transaction means storing the infromation in the block. So Transaction only happens when you store data in the blockchain

Comment: I think what is misleading me is that I've read there is an instance of a smart contract per block. It seems, then, that the smart contract is almost like an API which gets and sets data in the block chain? So is the smart contract essentially equivalent to middleware I may choose to write myself which manually persists data onto the block chain? Thanks again for your replies, very much appreciated

Comment: Smart Contract takes the rules of Transaction and implement it in a Code as a law. Let suppose if you want to implement smart contract About rental Apartment you will have some Basic rules before executing the Transaction so you write those rules in a Code and later Smart Contract take that Code as a Law to implement the Transaction as requirement met.

Comment: While the spirit of this answer is largely correct, note that many of the details are wrong. For example, the ABI for a contract is not stored in the blockchain at all. Compiling a smart contract produces (among other things) bytecode. Deploying a smart contract involves sending that bytecode in a transaction. This "init bytecode" is executed, and if execution is successful, it returns "runtime bytecode" which is then associated in the blockchain with the contract's address. That code is what is executed in the future when transactions are sent to that address.

Comment: ABIs are only JSON objects that are useful to interact with the real smartcontract (bytecode stored in the blockchain) using Javascript (web3js, nodejs).

Comment: Thank you @smarx and jfc for correcting i totally forgot About the Bytecode as i use truffle and Always see the json file

Answer (score 0):

> At what point does it persist data to the blockchain?

A smart contract has rules (functions) that control the way in which the data changes. Whenever you issue a function call, you are generating transactions. This transactions are the operations that change (or not) your SC data.

> What denotes a 'block' given the fact the examples simply look like classes - is each instance of these classes a 'block'?

Transactions are packed inside blocks, and a block can have several transactions operating in different SCs, or ETH accounts (wallets). The relation between SCs and blocks is the same as the relation between the code of any application and the way your database software works... mostly no relation.

This is: blocks are how blockchain stores data. A SC are the rules that say how your data changes.

> Is each block a 'version' of all of the properties which belong to a contract?

Nope. A block is a group of transactions. A transaction is an operation that changes your data.

> There is an instance of a smart contract per block

Nope. Only when you deploy a smart contract to the network, you send a complete copy of the bytecode of the compiled SC inside a special transaction that goes into a block. Even in this case, there can be more different transactions inside the block.

> The smart contract is almost like an API which gets and sets data in the block chain?

That's it

> Is the smart contract essentially equivalent to middleware I may choose to write myself

But talking about Ethereum, at the moment there's no choice: just solidity code (well there are a couple of more languages, but I think they are hardly used).